# Unable to build a list from JSON data with JQuery $.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Really just seems simple enough: been following the jquery docs; can't reason why this won't print a list to the specified div element.

```js
$(document).ready( function() {
 $.getJSON("dino.json", function(data) {
   $.each(data, function(key, val) {
   $("#triassic").html("<li class = " + key.name + ">" + key.name + "</li><br>") 
                 });
         });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "en">
<head>
<title>TEST</title>
<!-- my Script -->
<script src="dinoscriptTest.js"></script>
<!-- JQuery -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id = "triassic"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
[
{
"name":"T REX"
},
{
"name": "Triceratops"
},
{
"name": "Diplodocus"
}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

In your `$.each()`, your `key` is actually the index. Instead you should be pulling name from your variable `val`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. `key.name`, `key` is the index of the array. Please try `val.name`
2. `$("#triassic").html("<li class = " + key.name + ">" + key.name + "</li><br>")`, in each iteration, the div's content  will be replaced. Please try `$("#triassic").append("<li class = " + val.name + ">" + val.name + "</li><br>") 
                });`

Instead use,

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $.getJSON("dino.json", function(data) {
         $.each(data, function(key, val) {
            $("#triassic").append("<li class = '" + val.name + "'>" + val.name + "</li><br>") 
                 });
         });
});
```

Regards.